# 3 separate tables or 1 table with an extra column?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Database: MongoDB.

In my dataset, every record will have an attribute that can take on 1 of 3 values.

In terms of performance of query speed, would it be faster to have one table with a column that will store this attribute or have 3 separate tables for each of the values?

Comment: one general rule is that data that are asked together should be together, to avoid joins, unions etc. so i think it depends from your queries.If you ask for example in 1 query for all the 3 possible values, i think 1 collection maybe, but wait for better suggestions, and if you can give more information.

Comment: What kind of data are you storing in this field and what is its usage?

Comment: @prasad_ string. Its usage is to be able to distinguish the data

Comment: It depends upon how much data and how you want to use (query) it.